# use paperclip attachment as activeadmin site_title_image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have paperclip attachments saved in public folder. I need to use one of those images as a ActiveAdmin site title image.

For that i wrote as follows in the activeadmin.css.scss.erb:

```
#header h1.site_title {
   background: url('<%= Model.where(name: "logo").first.media_path.url %>') round 0 0;
}
```

Now if I edit this record named 'logo' with another image, the new image doesn't appear as site title image. And it shows the old one.

What has to be done to achieve this? or any other solution to use attachment as site title image?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a cash problem. Refresh the browser with CTL + F5

Comment: Tried but got same results. Also, i am getting the same URL as earlier when i inspect and check for background. Restarted rails server but getting same earlier URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right thing to do.

Consider this: if you prepare it for production, this css.erb file will become part of a giant css file and your background url will be the value when you compile the css file. And I am sure you don't want the css file gets recompiled every time user updates the logo.

To make it work, you need to pass this value to html.

Another option, ActiveAdmin has `site_title_image` option which must be set at boot. You can tweak it to support dynamic logo.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did it by writing SiteTitle component available with activeamdin.